# why UITextField becomeFirstResponder doesn't show keyboard in my child viewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, ipad, keyboard

In my first ViewController, I make one UITextField to becomeFirstResponder, and the focus stay that TextField and keyboard appear automatically. It just works fine. But then I present another child ViewController which has 3 UITextFields (A,B,C) in this ViewController, I set the first UITextField (say A) to becomeFirstResponder in this child ViewController, the focus stay the A but the keyboard doesn't appear. I searched all the answers the whole day, but nothing found.

Here is the code.

in parent VC, I set:

```
TestVC *testVC= [[TestVC alloc] init];
testVC.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[detailvc presentViewController:testVC animated:NO completion:nil];
```

in child VC TestVC, I set:

```
UITextField *v_matcode=[MyViewUtil addTextField:@"" x:10 y:10 width:100 height:40];
[self.view addSubview:v_matcode];
[v_matcode becomeFirstResponder];
```

and this is the addTextField():

```
+(UITextField *) addTextField:(NSString *)text x:(int)_x y:(int)_y width:(int)_width height:(int)_height {
  UITextField *v_txt = [[UITextField alloc] init];
  v_txt.frame= CGRectMake(_x, _y, _width, _height);
  v_txt.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
  return v_txt;}
```

The v_matcode has the focus, but the keyboard doesn't appear.  But if I don't set this textfield becomeFirstResponder and let user tap it,the keyboard appear correctly. Why is that?

Comment: What does the "`addTextField:`" code look like?  So far it looks like you're doing all the right things, but "`addTextField:`" is some custom method so it might be doing something wacky.

Comment: i agree with @michael-dautermann, can you please post the code of "addTextField:" method, that could help.

Comment: Can't test it now but try wrapping the call to becomeFirstResponder inside a dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ /* call here */});

Comment: You seem to be presenting your modal view controller from a different controller (i.e. not `self`) `[detailvc presentViewController:testVC animated:NO completion:nil];` is there any reason why and what is the relationship between `detailvc` and the view controller where you are making the `presentModalViewController` call from?

Comment: I'm guessing that you are adding your textField in loadView.  Try moving the becomeFirstResponder code into viewDidAppear, so that the view is already visible before trying to display the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

try setting animated to YES

[detailvc presentViewController:testVC animated:YES completion:nil];